# PHP Find date nearest to a timeline period

Tags: php, date, range, period

So, uh, ok. This might get mathematical, so hope you brought your scientific calculator with you ;)

This is my problem:

[image]

Given an initial date (timestamp), time period period (seconds) and today's date (timestamp), I need to find the nearest date which coincides with the period*n plus the original/initial date.

So far, I got some stuff working nicely, such as the amount of "periods" between the initial and final(today's) date, which would be "2" in the demo above:

```
$initial=strtotime('2 April 1991');
$time=time();
$period=strtotime('+10 years',0);

$periods=round(($time-$initial)/$period);
```

The next thing I did was:

```
$range=$periods*$period;
```

And finally:

```
echo date('d M Y',$initial+$range);
```

Which wrote '03 April 2011'. How did it get to 3? (I suspect it's a leap year issue?)
You know that feeling when you're missing something small? I'm feeling it all over me right now....

Comment: Unlike you, I'm testing your code and I get `01 Apr 2011`!

Comment: What?! Perhaps you should watch your false accusations. As it is, 01 April 1991 is wrong as well...

Comment: The periods are they set? Will they always be years or is that dynamic as well? If you only work with years you can just work on the year segment and you are home safe. If you need to work with days, you will get this leap year issue.

Comment: False accusations? I just ran your code and shared the results with you.

Comment: @ncuesta - I ran (*tested*) that code and got those results, I clearly stated so. I didn't just "invent" that date.
@Knubo - Yes, that is why it is strtotime. In the future people are supposed to mix them up, eg, `+1 year 2 months`.

Comment: @ncuesta There may be other variables into play here. There's no need for accusations.

Comment: I wasn't accusing no one, just said what were the results of running the script myself. Didn't say anything else. Sorry if Christian took it the wrong way, wasn't my intention.

Comment: That's ok, pardon accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok so if I understood what you are asking, you want to know the next date that will occurs in a given period of time (in your case, every 10 years starting from 2 April 1991, when will be the next date : 2 april 2011).

So, you should take a deeper look at the [DateTime](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php) class in PHP that is wayyyy better to use for the dates because it is more accurate. You mix it with [DateInterval](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/class.dateinterval.php) that match exactly what you need :

```
<?php
$interval = new DateInterval('P10Y'); // 10 years
$initial = new DateTime('1991-04-02');
$now = new DateTime('now');

while ($now->getTimestamp() > $initial->getTimestamp()) {
    $initial = $initial->add($interval);
}

echo $initial->format('d M Y'); // should return April 2, 2011 !
?>
```

Comment: Same issue with the other guy's question, mathematical implementation vs looping.

Comment: Works great for me. Just one thing: on the last line, it should be `echo $initial->format('d M Y');`.

Comment: @Christian Sciberras : you can try to do your math system on the Date object : `round(($now-$initial)/$interval) * $interval`. I can't test it right now so I can't confirm it will work. OR, you'll have to add the `->getTimestamp()` in each vars for your mathematical way. (to test). Tell me if it works, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Note that this will find the closest date *before* now, rather than the closest before or after.  This is like running `floor` rather than `round` in the original question.

Comment: yeah, you're right @lonesomeday, I misinterpreted nearest and "closest after"

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
$current = $initial = strtotime('2 April 1991');
$time_span = '+10 years';

while ($current < time())
{ 
  $current = strtotime($time_span, $current);
}

echo date('d M Y', $current);
```

Comment: I got `2 April 1991`. I was making on a more mathematical approach than via loops (which tend to get costly on higher ranges). I'm supposed to get it working on monthly and weekly checks as well, making it quite slow.

Answer (score 1):

What happened:

`+10 years` from *Year 0* (1970) will include 3 leap years '72, '76 and '80, but from '91 till '11 there are only five leap years '92, '96, '00, '04 and '08. You added that period twice, so because there weren't 6 leap years you got one extra day.

What you need to do:

Ad the period with `strtotime` one step at a time.

```
$period = "+10 years";
$newTime = $startingTime;
while(<condition>){
    $newTime = strtotime($period, $newTime);
}
```

Comment: AH! I get it. Should have been: strtotime('+1 years',0)*10

Comment: @Christian Sciberras NO! :) Do a while and add using `strtotime`. I posted some mockup code. If you do `strtotime('+1 years',0)*3` you'll get 5 days short of what you need. (March 28, probably.)

Comment: That `while` is exactly what I wrote, but Christian is looking for a mathematical approach on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a fix to [cx42net's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509115/php-find-date-nearest-to-a-timeline-period/4509230#4509230):

```
<?php

$initial = new DateTime('2 April 1991');
$now = new DateTime('now');
$interval = new DateInterval('P10Y');

$curDate = $initial;

while (true) {
    $curDate = $curDate->add($interval);

    $curDiff = $curDate->diff($now)->days;

    if (isset($lastDiff) && ($curDiff > $lastDiff)) {
        echo $lastDate->format('d M Y');
        break;
    } else {
        $lastDate = clone $curDate;
        $lastDiff = $curDiff;
    }
}
```